# Grep: Find 3 consecutive char and then follow another char or end of the line

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

I want to find 3 consecutive characters and then another character or the end of the line. I tried this:

```
egrep '(.)\1{2}' file
```

but I need less results.

Comment: It works fine for me.  If it is still not working for you, please show (a) some sample input, (b) the output that you see,  and (c) your desired output.

Comment: What is the `another char or end of line` supposed to restrict? The only case I can see is a file which ends exactly with the 3 identical characters, and that is not a text file - a text file is either empty or it ends with a newline on unix. Are you trying to restrict to *exactly* 3 consecutive characters, so `this is more aaaa letter a` would not match? Note in that example the last three characters in `aaaa` and the following space match your requirement of 3 consecutive characters and then another char.

Answer (score 0):

Can't make this work with grep, but I can make it work with egrep:
`egrep -o '([[:print:]\d])\1\1([[:print:]]|$)'`
That will match 3 consecutive characters, followed by *either* white space, a single printable character, or an end of line character.

Note: The -o prevents the issue of aBBBf matching and will show only BBBf.

Comment: `egrep` is simply `grep -E`

Comment: Yes. egrep is grep -E on "new" Unix. In my "old school days," I don't remember egrep being an alias to grep -E. Since the OP didn't say when flavor of Unix he was using, and appears to be a non-native English speaker. Wouldn't you agree it's best to stick to old-school POSIX because we know it   will work?